# Retrofit2: How to properly check the validity of response.body()?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

Since version `retrofit2.retrofit:2.3.0` I'm getting `NullPointerException` warnings on `response.body()` even when checking the body for `null` before:

[image]

```
Method invocation 'getCar()' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

In the changelog for `2.3.0` was an entry related to null checks:

> Retrofit now uses @Nullable to annotate all possibly-null values. [...] We use @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault and all parameters and return types are never null unless explicitly annotated @Nullable.

**It that the intended behavior?** In my point of view `response.body()` should be immutable, so my check in Picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69uIG.png) should not show a warning.

This is not a question about `NullPointerExceptions` - it's about the way how to handle responses of Retrofit2 properly. To not have warnings at the moment I have to do something like this:

```
if(response != null) {
    CarResponseBody body = response.body();
    if (body != null && body.getCar() != null){
        CarResponse car = body.getCar();
    }
}
```

A lot of code to just check if there is a valid response...

Comment: Perhaps it's warning because `body()` may return a non-null value on the first call, then a null value on the second call?

Comment: The warning is theoretically correct. Just because `body()` returns something the first time you call it, doesn't mean it won't return null the next time you call it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I know what a NullPointerException is, thank you! The problem is more like Jon Skeet said: Why `body()` may return something different at the second call? I'll edit the question ab bit.

Comment: It would be nice to have someone from Retrofit answering that question or at least give some advice since they recommend posting such things in stackoverflow and not opening an issue on GitHub

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is that the intended behavior?

If you check the JavaDoc of `Response<T>` you can read

> @Nullable public T body()
>   The deserialized response body of a **successful** response.
>   [Javadoc: Response](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/)

As it suggests, `body()` won't be `null` if the response was successful. To check for success you have `isSuccessful()` which

> Returns true if code() is in the range [200..300).

So the `@Nullable` is a valid choice, since the response can be `null` in any non-success case, e.g. no network, an invalid request, or some other error.

The hint in your IDE is a lint warning that checks your source code for possible sources of common errors or bugs.

This is *why* `body()` might be `null` and why lint reports this as a warning in the first place.

> In my point of view response.body() should be immutable, so my check in Picture 1 should not show a warning.

And in theory you're correct. You and I both know that `body()` is not mutable, but the problem here is that *this* lint *check* has no way of knowing.

```
T res1 = response.body(); // could be null
T res2 = response.body(); // ...maybe still null?
```

Lint is a static source and byte code analyzer that helps to prevent common bugs and errors and one of those lint checks tries to prevent NPEs. If you annotate a method `@Nullable` all the check knows is that the returned value *could* be `null` and it will raise a warning if you try to operate on the result of the call directly.

```
// does response return the same value twice? who knows?
response.body() != null && response.body().getCar() != null
```

The way you handle your response is actually the only way to get rid of the lint warning—other than suppressing or disabling it.

By assigning it to a local variable you are able to ensure that a value is not `null` at some point and that it won't become `null` in the future, and lint is also able to see that.

```
CarResponseBody body = response.body(); // assign body() to a local variable
if (body != null && body.getCar() != null) { // variable is not null
    CarResponse car = body.getCar(); // safe to access body, car is also not null
    // everything is fine!
}
```

---

> It that the intended behavior?

Yes. `@Nullable` is a good way to hint that a method might return `null` and you should also use it in your own code if you return `null` on some paths *because* lint can warn of possible NullPointerExceptions.

If a method might return `null` you will have to assign it to a local field and check the field for `null` values, or you risk that the value could have changed.

```
Car car = response.getBody(); // car could be null
if(car != null) {
  // car will never be null
}
```

#### Different options / approaches

I see that you also additionally seem to wrap your response object in an additional layer.

```
CarResponseBody body = response.body();
Car car = body.getCar()
```

If you want to remove complexity from your code, you should have a look at how to remove this wrapping `*ResponseBody` at an earlier stage. You can do so by registering your own Converter and adding additional handling there. You can see more about this on this [Retrofit talk by Jake Wharton](https://youtu.be/t34AQlblSeE?t=1650)

Another completely different approach would be to use RxJava with Retrofit which removes the need to check the response yourself. You'll either get a success or an error, which you can handle the Rx way.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation! I'll take a look at the Converters, that seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create an isValid() or hasResults() method in the WhateverResponse class

```
boolean isValid(){
return getCar() != null && getWheel() != null && somethingElse
}
```

usage

```
if(response.isValid()){
//do your other if's
}
```

checking for null response isn't necessary. errorBody() will be not null or the retrofit2.Callback onFailure() method will be invoked before that happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (response != null) {CarResponseBody body= new CarResponseBody(); if (response.raw().code() == 200 && response.body()!=null) {
body = response.body();if(body.getCar()!=null){ CarResponse car =body.getCar()}}}
```