# How to identify if the JSON response data is empty or not from server using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am retrieveing a list of data from server to be displayed into recyclerview in android using retrofit.
The retrieval is working fine, the data called is displayed and no problem.

But the problem is, I want to check if the data I get is empty or not, because I want to do some action from this checking.

I've tried this code but it keeps checking *only* successful do the request, *not* the JSON data content that it brought from server.

```
getData.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {

if (response.body() != null){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data is not empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
// want to do some action here after the checking
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data isempty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
someList = new ArrayList<ModelItem>();
someList= response.body().getItem();
adapter= new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), someList);

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_connection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
```

I want to check the inner response if it empty or not, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434716/retrofit2-how-to-properly-check-the-validity-of-response-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code, before you map Json to POJO.

```
String response = basicResponse.getResponse();
if(response!=null){
   String responseBody = response.body();
   if(!responseBody.isEmpty()){
      // non empty response, you can map Json via Gson to POJO classes...

   }
   else{
       // empty response...
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with map sir. I already have POJO, which contains setter and getter.. and also the `!responseBody.isEmpty()` will only listen to success/unsuccess calling as I tried..

Comment: Okay, that's not the question, the question is how to check the empty response which this code does.

Comment: Yes, I mean how to check if the data inside the response are empty, not responded or not sir

Comment: I fixed it by using `isEmpty` to the model. ex: `if (response.body().getYoutModel().isEmpty()){}`

Answer (score 1):

First check validation of response then it's body and then do rest of the work under there:

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {

    if ( response.body() != null){
    someList = new ArrayList<ModelItem>();
    someList= response.body().getItem();
    adapter= new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), someList);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
    // want to do some action here after the checking
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data isempty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_connection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    });
```

Comment: The `if (response != null && response.body() != null)` makes android lint shows that it is the same as `if (response.body() != null)` sir, it return the same..

Answer (score 0):

This May Help you.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

  String responseBody = response.body();

   if(!responseBody.isEmpty()){
      // Create here  Json via Gson to POJO classes...
               try {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Model>>() {
                        }
                                .getType();
                        objModel= gson.fromJson(responseBody, type);
                    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

   }
   else{
       // empty response...
   }

    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_connection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to assign `response.body()` to a String - you will need to call the string method on it like:

```
String responseBody = response.body().string();
```